# Auto relabel all labels in a tex file

Tags: labels, editors, kile

I have a standard .tex file and I use Kile on Ubuntu 16.04. My question is the following: 
I would like to find all strings with `\label{***}` and replace them automatically with `\label{***_B}`.

How can I go about doing that?

Comment: Does Kile has the possibility to search-and-replace using *regular expressions*? If so do `\\label\{(.*?)\}` as search text and `\label{\1_B}` as replace text. The `(.*?)` is a wildcard for "any text" which can be reinserted using `\1`.

Comment: Following up on @MartinScharrer's comment: Yes, Kile can do that. Edit -> Replace (Ctrl + R), select "Regular expression" from the "Mode" drop-down (just below the Replace-field).

Comment: @MartinScharrer Would you like to write up an answer?